# Looking for advice on storing, reading, and dynamically updating data in XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I'm a bit of a newbie to C# and I've never done anything with XML. Most of my experience is C code written for microcontrollers, with some C/C++ and linux scripting experience, but never any XML.

Basically, I've got a bunch of firmware update files in a folder, currently about 50, but users could have as many as a hundred or more, especially if they don't delete old versions or the program gets expanded to support additional hardware. My program needs to check all those files, parse a little data out of them, and store it in some fashion for quick lookup. I thought about just doing a CSV file, but figured I might as well learn a little about XML in the process.

My first problem is formatting the data. One firmware file may cover multiple hardware models, and there can be multiple versions of the firmware for one model. When the program starts, it will need to make a list of all the file names currently in the XML file and compare them to those in the folder. Later it will need to find all the files with the right model name. I've come up with a couple different formats for storing the data, I'm currently leaning towards option 2.

Option 1:

```
<Model model="Model String">
    <FirmwareFile filename=foo.bar> 
        <Version> "1.2.3" </Version>
        <DateCode> "05082015" </DateCode>
    </FirmwareFile>
    <FirmwareFile filename=foo2.bar>
        [...]
    </FirmwareFile>
</Model>
```

Option 2:

```
<FirmwareFile filename=foo.bar> 
    <Models>"Model A", "Model B"</Models> //probably not the right way to do this
    <Version> "1.2.3" </Version>
    <DateCode> "05082015" </DateCode>
</FirmwareFile>
```

The other problem is which library and which method of retrieving the data would be best. The way I see it, I have two options for working with the file, either I read through it on the disk twice (the first time reading file names, the second time to look up model numbers) and write/delete entries from it directly, or else I read all the data once into memory (probably a list of a class), and if anything changes rewrite the file. Which way should I be going? And which library should I be using?

Comment: Might be closed as primarily opinion based, but anyway. Don't put strings in quotes, it's not needed in XML. Also it would be more logical to me to handle files and write information about them, since it is information about files you're writing. Second would seem better then, but don't put models like that. `<Models><Model>Model A</Model><Model>Model B</Model></Models>` would be a lot better. You want to use quick lookups, so having them in separate tags is best.

Comment: It sounds like you should be using some sort of database instead of XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at my - **ready-to-use** - code sample.

First of all, you need to create a pair of classes, for handling those models:

```
//using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Models
{
    public List<Model> models { get; set; }
}

public class Model
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<FirmwareFile> firmwarefiles { get; set; }
}

public class FirmwareFile
{
    public string filename { get; set; }
    public Version version { get; set; }
    public int datecode { get; set; }
}
```

After that here come the methods to save and load it.

First the `Load` method:

```
//using System.Xml;

public Models Load()
{
    Models ms = new Models();
    ms.models = new List<Model>();
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.Load(/*path to your file*/);
    foreach (XmlNode model in xml.LastChild.ChildNodes)
    {
        Model m = new Model();
        m.firmwarefiles = new List<FirmwareFile>();
        m.name = model.FirstChild.InnerText;
        foreach (XmlNode firmwarefile in model.LastChild.ChildNodes)
        {
            FirmwareFile f = new FirmwareFile();
            f.filename = firmwarefile.ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
            Version v = new Version();
            Version.TryParse(firmwarefile.ChildNodes[1].InnerText, out v);
            f.version = v;
            f.datecode = Convert.ToInt32(firmwarefile.ChildNodes[2].InnerText);
            m.firmwarefiles.Add(f);
        }
        ms.models.Add(m);
    }
    return ms;
}
```

Second the `Save` method:

```
//using System.Xml;

public void Save(Models models)
{
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(/*path to your config file*/))
    {
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        writer.WriteRaw("\n");
        writer.WriteStartElement("models");
        foreach (Model m in models.models)
        {
            writer.WriteRaw("\n\t");
            writer.WriteStartElement("model");
            writer.WriteRaw("\n\t\t");
            writer.WriteElementString("name", m.name);
            writer.WriteRaw("\n\t\t");
            writer.WriteStartElement("firmwarefiles");
            for (int i = 0; i < m.firmwarefiles.Count; i++)
            {
                writer.WriteRaw("\n\t\t\t");
                writer.WriteStartElement("firmwarefile");
                writer.WriteRaw("\n\t\t\t\t");
                writer.WriteElementString("filename", m.firmwarefiles[i].filename);
                writer.WriteRaw("\n\t\t\t\t");
                writer.WriteElementString("version", m.firmwarefiles[i].version.ToString());
                writer.WriteRaw("\n\t\t\t\t");
                writer.WriteElementString("datecode", m.firmwarefiles[i].datecode.ToString());
                writer.WriteRaw("\n\t\t\t");
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }
            writer.WriteRaw("\n\t\t");
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteRaw("\n\t");
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
        writer.WriteRaw("\n");
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndDocument();
    }
}
```

`Save` returns kind a this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<models>
    <model>
        <name>foo1</name>
        <firmwarefiles>
            <firmwarefile>
                <filename>foo1.firm</filename>
                <version>15.22.13.56</version>
                <datecode>30051982</datecode>
            </firmwarefile>
            <firmwarefile>
                <filename>foo2.firm</filename>
                <version>12.13.14</version>
                <datecode>12031967</datecode>
            </firmwarefile>
        </firmwarefiles>
    </model>
</models>
```

**Basic usage:**

```
Models models = Load();
Save(models);
```

Comment: You could use XML Serialization instead of manually reading and writing the XML.  Much simpler to work with... https://blog.udemy.com/csharp-serialize-to-xml/

Comment: @paul that's true, but i prefer doing it manu aly as I can choose the "design" of xml how I want it to be.... Another thing is, I hate the header" design" which is created by the serialization... It's more code to write, but in final `code is poetry` && i love code... :)

Answer (score 0):

For datetime, you could use a unix timestamp too.
What I used for a previous xml project:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument(); //Get the XML from remote URL
xml.Load(/*url or location*/);
foreach (XmlNode firmwareFile in xml)
{
    //do something
}
```

Get the inner text of a xml node:

```
string inner = lesson["yourxmlnode"].InnerText;
```

Just updated my file every day at 2:00

I hope this helped you a little bit, but I need more information for giving more code.